# Samsung S3 - connection problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have installed Samsung PC Studio on my notebook and connected my Samsung Galaxy S3 to it by USB.  The notebook picks it up and I can open it in My Computer.

But when I go to PC Studio 7, I "click here to connect a phone" and get a message saying "there is no available connection type and therefore connection cannot be established".

I go to Settings - Manage Connections - there is nothing in the Connections Available box.

I did a Samsung PC Studio 7 upgrade on my notebook, which worked fine until it got to a point saying "no phone connected". I had to repair the PC Studio installation.

Anyone able to help, please?  I can't see anywhere on the phone to activate the usb port, or suchlike!

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for your phone on the PC?

Comment: Yes. Software is installed.